# Why do I get a blank page after omniauth authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, callback, omniauth

I'm using Facebook and Twitter login on my rails application. When I try login on localhost:3000 or in heroku it works fine, but when the application runs in a VPS I get a blank page after URI redirect.

This is what I get...

Facebook

```
http://myapp.mydomain.com:8080/auth/facebook/callback?code=XXxxxxXXXxxxxxxx_CjM5VsqUy1DzUdfIKHQNpA8maZj0Pi0fMUYnZRzf-8aPVtiZp1Jxm356CCYNvnB-z7cjutL5BaSpqDN_QmUwvmt4CEyBbHyLsVhPpmFVWv-b75Wq0oqWNNsiiqMybCdrCEJVL3FUbX05M8hrf7zLWcBNiFCD75ENCoP3S02vrcQAzjbErqj5lER9WSVGpA9ZrLFM2rM13iPvWMY0jVRgX9xOmK7EjcnBuoxgj8DelTtHXJZAWACydxpHq16UtQoNP21ayOf_dG8VCbsv7CP6rMzLAdkCMAJOgRXkzuSSY09B8zfv7w#_=_
```

Twitter

```
http://myapp.mydomain.com:8080/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=XXxxxxXXXxxxi0YsAAABVFuVvEM&oauth_verifier=XXxxxxXXXxXH1tvZjWhvlqyfHXr6Z7Dg
```

Why it works on Heroku but not in my VPS?

> Deploy: capistrano and unicorn on nginx

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Did you set up the correct redirect_uris?

Comment: Yes, I have checked many times the correct redirect_uris. Could it be a problem with the port? @cars10

Comment: If you added the port to the redirect_uri it should not be an issue with that. @ronny-valdivieso  so i ask again - what do the logs say? facebook & twitter usally send good error messages when using oauth

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error `I, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.813607 #27396] INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms) F, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.815961 #27396] FATAL -- :` @cars10 I've put an answer with the last request.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I found in production.log file @cars10** `I, [2016-04-29T05:31:00.620561 #27396]  INFO -- : Started GET "/favicon.ico" for MY.IP at 2016-04-29 05:31:00 -0500
F, [2016-04-29T05:31:00.631769 #27396] FATAL -- : 
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:56.965447 #27396]  INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/twitter" for MY.IP at 2016-04-29 05:31:56 -0500
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:56.967894 #27396]  INFO -- : (twitter) Request phase initiated.
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:57.424362 #27396]  INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/twitter" for MY.IP at 2016-04-29 05:31:57 -0500
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:57.425610 #27396]  INFO -- : (twitter) Request phase initiated.
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:59.559228 #27396]  INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=XxXxXQAAAAAAi0YsAAABVGGTpic&oauth_verifier=XxXxX6lUHiXEcOjMlFKYwcFbtXWyq3Sl" for MY.IP at 2016-04-29 05:31:59 -0500
I, [2016-04-29T05:31:59.561975 #27396]  INFO -- : (twitter) Callback phase initiated.
I, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.808098 #27396]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.808446 #27396]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"XxXxXQAAAAAAi0YsAAABVGGTpic", "oauth_verifier"=>"XxXxX6lUHiXEcOjMlFKYwcFbtXWyq3Sl", "provider"=>"twitter"}
D, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.811309 #27396] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["provider", "twitter"], ["uid", "259939960"]]
I, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.813607 #27396]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
F, [2016-04-29T05:32:00.815961 #27396] FATAL -- :`

Comment: You left out the interesting parts. Just check what it says and fix the server error - mentioned right after you cut the log

Comment: That's the problem, this is the last part of the log file, there's no more details after this. @cars10